# Java - Objective C Socket UTF8 Problem

Tags: java, iphone, sockets, utf-8, nsstring

I'm programming a little Client - Server program.
The Server is in Java and the Client IOS.
On the Server i use java.net.ServerSocket and on the Client the LXSocket. Sending Data (Integer, Double, Float, UTF8 String) from Client to Server works perfect, but when i'm trying to send a UTF8 String back to the Client it kinda fails. I can receive the message, but not convert it to a NSString.

Java sending Code:

```
public void sendMessage(java.net.Socket socket) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    int i = swabInt(64);
    stream.writeInt(i);
    String message = "Message to send as UTF8.";
    int len = swabInt(message.length());
    stream.writeInt(len);
    stream.write(nachricht.getBytes("UTF8"));
}
```

IOS receiving Code:

```
-(IBAction)createSocket {
LXSocket *socket = [[[LXSocket alloc] init] autorelease];
[socket connect:@"localhost" port:11111];

int i = [socket readInt];
int len = [socket readInt];
NSData *data = [socket readBytesWithLength:len];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Receiving the Stream works, but when i'm trying to init the NSString it crashes.
Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Transmission works fine, but i found out something strange. I tried out this code:

```
NSString *test = @"The Message";
    const char *c = [test UTF8String];`
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:c];
NSLog(@"Decoding: %s", string);
```

But my Console says:

```
2011-03-17 22:51:27.555 Sockets[8641:207] Decoding: ¿Ø‚
```

So is there any way to get a NSString from this char array encoded with UTF8??

Comment: Any particular reason you're going so low level? Unless you have a specific need, I'd recommend just using a simple web framework in a standard web container. Then serve XML responses (RESTEasy or XStream for example) and use NSXMLParser on the iOS side. It'll be easier to debug (use your web browser), configure (Tomcat with thread management, etc.) and maintain as your protocol evolves. I've taken this approach to quickly put a client/server program together.

Comment: I thought about using XML responses or even Webservices, but they are too slow. Later the messages will be bigger and contain other data such as images ect.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `LXSocket` to answer your question, however I notice you're sending the length as `message.length()`. That's going to return the number of characters instead of the number of bytes. You'll want to return the length of the bytes from `getBytes("UTF8")`. It won't solve your problem right now, however it'll be a problem once/if you start sending characters above 127.

Comment: Oh you're right, didn't see that.

Comment: The LXSocket handles all transmission work, you can use writeInteger, Short, ect. Is there also an encoding like little endian for Integer? Or is there something missing in the bytestream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i figured it out...
Plain stupidity...

```
NSLog(@"%s", theString);
```

instead of

```
NSLog(@"%@", theString);
```

Epic fail.